# jquery click handler called twice for only one click. (No bubbling!)

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jquery event handler, which seems to be firing twice for a single click:

Here's the handler in gizmo.js

```
$( function() {
   $('.nametag').click( function () {
       event.stopImmediatePropagation();
       alert("My name is" + $(this).data('username') + "and my user name is " + $(this).data('uid'));

   })
});
```

Here's the html:

```
<p class="nametag" data-username="Michael Gimby" data-uid="227">My name is Michael Gimby</p>
```

There is no other elements on the page with class 'nametag' and as you cann see the handler is tied to the innermost tag so I doesn't seem like a bubbling problem (which should have been solved to stopImmediatePropagation  anyway.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce the same issue in a Jsfiddle? Also you can inspect the element and browse it's event handler click section to see all the click events binded to it. If you are still not able to figure out the issue I can provide a solution for the above given info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to put `event` inside function

```
$('.nametag').click( function (event) {
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();
   alert("My name is" + $(this).data('username') + "and my user name is " + $(this).data('uid'));

})
```